# Install Helm on Raspberry PI 3?

Tags: kubernetes, raspberry-pi3, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-health-check

I have tried to search for how to install Helm on Raspberry PI 3 (ARM), but I have just found fragments of information here and there.

What are the steps to install Helm on a Raspberry Pi 3 running Raspbian Stretch?

Answer (score 4):

```
export HELM_VERSION=v2.9.1
export HELM_INSTALL_DIR=~/bin
mkdir bin
wget https://kubernetes-helm.storage.googleapis.com/helm-$HELM_VERSION-linux-arm.tar.gz
tar xvzf helm-$HELM_VERSION-linux-arm.tar.gz
mv linux-arm/helm $HELM_INSTALL_DIR/helm
rm -rf linux-arm
helm list
helm init --tiller-image=jessestuart/tiller:v2.9.1
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could describe what the script does and not just plainly pasting it here. It would also help others later.

Comment: It downloads the specific version of Helm for ARM. Unpacks it and moves it to your bin folder and initialises helm

Answer (score 1):

I get along with:

`kubectl -n kube-system create serviceaccount tiller && kubectl create clusterrolebinding tiller --clusterrole cluster-admin --serviceaccount=kube-system:tiller && helm init --service-account tiller --tiller-image=jessestuart/tiller:v2.9.1 --override spec.selector.matchLabels.'name'='tiller',spec.selector.matchLabels.'app'='helm' --history-max 10 --output yaml | sed 's@apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1@apiVersion: apps/v1@' | kubectl apply -f -`